# Apache mod_rewrite - adding trailing slash to existing file creates a problemo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my existing `.htaccess` script

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Everything works fine except when I add a trailing slash at the end of a url, I get 500 error.

i.e. `http://example.com/dir/file` works, but not
`http://example.com/dir/file/` --> error 500 (redirected too many times) instead of error 404.

Can someone pls help me out?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: write 2 conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [NC,L]
```

Capture the trailing slash and redirect to the file without trailing slash. If no trailing slash found, then simply add `.php` (or other extension) to it.